# How to pass hidden field of user_id to comment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hidden-field

I am trying to add a hidden field in `comments/_form` so the name of the user shows up in the comments section. Nothing I do works. I really want to use a hidden field so I know how to make it work.

User has many comments, and comments belongs to user.

This is what I currently have in `comments/_form`:

```
  <%= form_for([@place, @place.comments.build]) do |f| %>
     <%= hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>
  <p>
     <%= f.label :body %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
     <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
```

This is what I currently have in `_comment.html.erb` Please note the `comment.user.first_name`.

This is the error I get `undefined method`first_name' for nil:NilClass`:

```
 <p>
   <strong>Comment:</strong><br />
    <%= comment.user.first_name %> wrote:<br /><br>
    <%= comment.body %>
</p> 

<p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.place, comment],
           method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
 </p>
```

This is what I have in `comments_controller`

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController

   def create
     @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
     @comment = @place.comments.create(comment_params)
     redirect_to place_path(@place)
   end

  def destroy
    @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
    @comment = @place.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
   redirect_to place_path(@place)
 end

 private
   def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :user_id)
   end
 end
```

This is what I have in the `ApplicationController`:

```
   helper_method :current_user 

   private 
     def current_user 
     @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
```

Does anyone have any advice?

**EDIT** I'm adding in a couple more stuff for edification in case it helps.

**Users controller**

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @user = User.new
    end

   def create 
    @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save 
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed Up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

 end

 private
   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
   end
```

**Sessions controller**

```
  class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   def new
    end

   def create
      user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      if user
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to places_path, :notice => "Logged in!"
      else
        flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
       render "new"
      end
   end

   def destroy 
      session[:user_id] = nil
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
    end

  end
```

**Places controller**

```
 class PlacesController < ApplicationController

  def index 
     @places = Place.all 
   end 


  def new
    @place = Place.new
  end

  def create
    @place = Place.new(place_params)

    if @place.save 
       redirect_to @place
   else 
    render 'new'
  end
 end

 def show
   @place = Place.find(params[:id])
 end

def edit 
   @place = Place.find(params[:id])
 end 

 def update
   @place = Place.find(params[:id])
   if @article.update(place_params)
     redirect_to @place 
   else
     render 'edit'
  end
 end 

 def destroy 
   @place = Place.find(params[:id])
   @place.destroy 

   redirect_to places_path 
 end


end

 private 
  def place_params
    params.require(:place).permit(:name, :location)
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to send it through a hidden_field, instead, remove it.

Rewrite your `create` method as follows:

```
def create
  @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
  @comment = @place.comments.create(comment_params)
  @comment.user = current_user
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to place_path(@place)
  else
    render "comments/_form"
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Rajesh Omanakuttan, thank you for taking the time to respond. I have implemented what you suggested in your answer, ie, removing the hidden field and adding what you suggested in create method above. Left everything else intact. I still receive an error. It's either the name is blank but at least the post and comment shows up OR I get this `undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass`. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Weird thing, I just tried `<%= comment.user.email %>` in `_comment.html.erb`, and it shows the email address in some posts OR this error `undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass`. But the point is that it shows the email address! Why does it do for that but not for first name? Oh sorry, just for clarification, this is with the altered code as stated in comment above.

Comment: I think its `@comment` rather than `comment`.

Comment: Omankuttan, just tried that and got this `undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass`. This is above this: `
NoMethodError in Places#show` if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This is not an answer for the initial question, this is the fix for the error (but its too large for a comment)

Error is because, the `current_user` returns `nil`, there are two options depending your requirement,

1 )

```
CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :current_user
  ...
end
```

2)

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_filter :current_user
   .....
end
```

---- updated method

```
   def current_user 
     if session[:user_id] 
       @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
     else
       #redirect user to login to set the session[:user_id] variable
     end 
    end
```

Comment: no dice. Tried it in both. Still got this error `undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass`. Everything else is intact except for changes suggested by initial answer. Have updated my post with additional in case it helps. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: oops, one thing is missing in my comment, if you dont have a `session[:user_id]` , then you should redirect users to login, ( updated my answer..)

Comment: I do have `sessions[:user_id]`. Please look at my sessions controller. If I understand the implication of your `sessions[:user_id]` comment, I'm not trying to have first_name displayed when logged in only but ALSO when logged out.